# php having an issue with my if condition

Tags: php, date, comparison, conditional-statements

I'm seem to be having a problem with my if condition. 
Whenever I enter an license that is expired more than 31 days it goes inside the condition where when then license expiry date is greater 31 days it will give a green coloured circle and green text. 
It reads it as both expired and will not expire until 31 days giving a red and green coloured circle and text.

Here's a snippet.

```
$exp = strtotime($exp_date);

$td = strtotime($today_date);

$diff= $td -$exp;

$x = abs(floor($diff/ (60 * 60 * 24)));


$alertdays = ""; //expired

$alertdays1 = ""; //less than 30 days before expiry

$alertdays2 = ""; //more than 30 days




$statusexp = ""; //expired

$status = ""; //less than 30 days
$status1 = ""; //more than 30 days

$daysexp = ""; //days expired


if($td > $exp)
{
$statusexp = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:30px; color:red;"></i>';
}


if($diff < 0){
$status = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:30px; color:orange;"></i>';
}

if($diff <= 30) {

$alertdays1 = $x. ""; 

}
if($x >= 31){
$alertdays1 = "";
$alertdays2 = $x. "";
$status ='<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:30px; color:green;"></i>'; 
}


if($td > $exp){
$alertdays ="Expired";
$daysexp  = " - " . $x; 
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC3PQ.jpg)

Comment: Please supply a small battery of test cases (two dates each test case) and your expected output for each test case.  ...no images please.

Comment: If you are going to conditionally echo an empty string, don't bother.  Just remove the else component entirely.

Comment: Surely you don't need to have so many variables for this task, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is that you use `ABS` function to calculate the difference of today and the target date. If you use `2018-02-01` to test it, the result should be -41, but with ABS you got 41, so you code give "green" result.

Answer (score 0):

you can create function

for example:

```
<?php
function Mehrdad_Diff_Alldate($startTime) {
$start_date = new DateTime($startTime);
$endTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($endTime));
$text=$since_start->y.'|'.$since_start->m.'|'.$since_start->days.'|'.$since_start->h.'|'.$since_start->i.'|'.$since_start->s.'|';
return $text;   
}

$td =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$exp="2007-08-12 13:10:56";
$exps = Mehrdad_Diff_Alldate($exp);
$explode=explode("|",$exps);
$year=$explode[0];
$month=$explode[1];
$day=$explode[2];
$hours=$explode[3];
$mintue=$explode[4];
$second=$explode[5];
?>
```

Now you can use from $day
Just try to not divide these terms separately

for example:

```
<?php
if($td > $exp){

}else if($day < 0){

}else if($day <= 30) {

}else if($day >= 31){

}else if($td > $exp){

}else{

}
?>
```

Comment: it worked sir. thank you very much!! can you care to explain my mistake so that I can review it?